# How to replace Login/SignUp with Log out using React and Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

Im working on a project and we have set up a firebase database to remember people who sign up, but i need to replace the login/signup link on the navbar with logout, and make the user log out, but i have no idea how to do it using our current code. if anyone has any ideas on how to do it then i would appreciate it
the navbar looks like this, its called Toolbar.js

```
import React from 'react';
import DrawerToggleButton from '../SideDrawer/DrawerToggleButton';
import './Toolbar.css';
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

//navbar for the browser
const toolbar = props => (
        <header className="toolbar">
            <nav className="toolbar_navigation">
                <div className="toolbar_toggle-button">
                <DrawerToggleButton click={props.drawerClickHandler}/>
                </div>

                <div className="toolbar_logo">
                   <a href="./home">
                    < img src= "./images/logowm3.png"/></a>
                </div>

                <div className="toolbar_brand">
                   <a href="./home">
                    <img src="./images/logowondermom4.png"/>
                   </a>
                </div>

                <div className="spacer" />
                <div className="toolbar_navigation-items">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <Link to="home">Home</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <Link to="about">About</Link>
                        </li>

                        <li className="dropdown">
                            <Link to="programs">Programs<i className="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></Link>
                                <div className="dropdown-content">
                            <Link to="sixWeekProgram">6 Week program</Link>
                            <Link to="weekOne">Week 1 </Link>
                            <Link to="dayOne">Day 1</Link>
                                </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                        <li className="dropdown">
                        <Link to="nutrition">Nutrition<i className="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></Link>
                            <div className="dropdown-content">
                        <Link to="breakfast">Breakfast</Link>
                        <Link to="lunch">Lunch</Link>
                        <Link to="dinner">Dinner</Link>
                        <Link to="snacks">Snacks</Link>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </li>
                        <li>
                        <Link to="login">Login/Sign up<i className="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i></Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
);

export default toolbar;
```

and the login code looks like this

```
import React from 'react';
import "./Login.css"
import { Component } from 'react'
import { Form, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

class Login extends Component {  

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        validation: {
            email: {
                status: 'pristine',
                error: ''
            },
            password: {
                status: 'pristine',
                error: ''
            },
            form: {
                disabled: true,
                error: ''
            }
        }
    }
}

  signup = () => {
    window.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      this.email, 
      this.password
  ).then(() => {
    window.location.href = '/home';
  }).catch(error => {

  });
  }



  login = () => {
    window.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      this.email,
      this.password
      ).then(() => {
        window.location.href = '/home';
      }).catch(error => {

      });
      }


validateEmail = (e) => {
  const value = e.target.value;
  const validation = { ...this.state.validation };
  const newStatus = /^[^@]+@[^@]+$/.test(value) ? 'is-valid' : 'is-invalid';
  if (newStatus != validation.email.status) {
      validation.email.status = newStatus;
      validation.email.error = newStatus == 'is-invalid' ? 'Not a valid email address!' : '';
      this.setState({ validation });
  }
  this.email = value;
  this.validateForm();
}


validatePassword = (e) => {
  const value = e.target.value;
  const validation = { ...this.state.validation };
  const newStatus = value.length > 5 ? 'is-valid' : 'is-invalid';
  if (newStatus != validation.password.status) {
      validation.password.status = newStatus;
      validation.password.error = newStatus == 'is-invalid' ? 'Must be at least 6 characters!' : '';
      this.setState({ validation });
  }
  this.password = value;
  this.validateForm();
}

validateForm() {
  const validation = { ...this.state.validation };
  const isFormDisabled = validation.email.status != 'is-valid' || validation.password.status != 'is-valid'; 
  if (isFormDisabled != validation.form.disabled) {
      validation.form.disabled = isFormDisabled;
      this.setState({ validation });
  }
}

  render() {  

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <div className="form-container">
        <Form>
          <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
              <Form.Label id="emailText">Email address</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter email" label="Email" name="email" className={this.state.validation.email.status} onChange={this.validateEmail} />
          </Form.Group>

          <Form.Group controlId="formBasicPassword">
              <Form.Label id="passwordText">Password</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Password" className={this.state.validation.password.status} label="Password"  name="password"  onChange={this.validatePassword}/>
            <Form.Text className="textpassword">
              Password needs to be at least 6 characters.
            </Form.Text>
          </Form.Group>

          <div className="text-center">
              <Button variant="primary btn-block" type="button" id="loginButton" disabled={this.state.validation.form.disabled} onClick={this.login}>
                Log In
              </Button>

              <Button variant="primary btn-block" type="button" id="signupButton" disabled={this.state.validation.form.disabled} onClick={this.signup}>
                 Sign Up
              </Button>
          </div>
        </Form>
      </div>
    </div> 
  );
  }
};

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 0):

are you saving the details of the user somewhere, If so then, in that case, you only need to create if-else case using ternary operator like if a user is not null then show LOGOUT button and pass a function onClick to delete the details otherwise LOGIN/Signup option should be shown?

```
{
                                (item.likes.includes(state._id))
                                ?
                                <i className="material-icons" 
                                onClick={()=>{unlikepost(item._id)}}
                                >thumb_down</i>
                                :
                                <i className="material-icons" style={{ color: "red" }}
                                onClick={()=>{likepost(item._id)}}
                                >thumb_up</i>
                                }
```

this is an example which I tried to use in my case, here I am checking if  the likes of the post(in my project) include my id then show dislike button otherwise show Like button.

Comment: the details are saved on the firebase yeah, so that includes the password and the email. I will try thank you :D

Comment: I am sorry but I am confused as to where I would write the if-else with the trenary operator. I am new to all of this so I'm trying to understand

Comment: no, you need to save the details in some form there because you will need it many times apart from navbar also, there is the concept of UseContext, learn that, it is mostly used for this process only to keep the user details, I am myself new to this so I don't know much but I will try to show an ex. of the itinerary operator,

Comment: Will try and implement what you wrote, thank you so much